# Mitakon lens and mount identification

Tags: lens, lens-mount, equipment-identification

I'm trying to identify this lens, and its mount. It is a Labled: "MITAKON MC ZOOM 1:4.5 f=80-200mm 55(diameter symbol) 845041"

The rear mount is pictured, its some kind of reverse-bayonet system. The rear outer ring rotates, so I would expect the camera to have the "male" bayonet mount.

Any ideas? I am trying to get it attached to a MFT camera, which I have done for other lenses with my 3D printer. I would also be willing to buy an adapter.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: oooh, is it a Cannon FD mount? I can't really tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be made for the Canon FD mount, but the rear of the lens with the control linkage for the aperture is missing.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I realized this was it. The linkage is missing because I removed it. (I really should have mentioned that.) I should have been able to answer this myself, I think I just sort of mentally ruled out Canon in my search for reverse-bayonet mounts.